# JavaScript object creation / associativity

Tags: javascript, constructor, associative-array

Can someone please explain the output behaviour of the following code snippet?

```
function Vertex(x, y, z) {
    this.x = parseInt(x);
    this.y = parseInt(y);
    this.z = parseInt(z);
};

var set = {};

var v1 = new Vertex(1,2,3);
var v2 = new Vertex(2,3,4);
var v3 = new Vertex(1,2,3);
var v4 = new Vertex(4,5,6);

set[v1] = 10;
set[v2] = 11;


alert(set[v1] + " " + set[v2] + " " + set[v3] + " " + set[v4]);
// Output: 11 11 11 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v1 == v2 == v3 == v4 == "[object Object]" when expressed as a string
```

You can't have an object as a key.

```
set[v1] is the same as set["[object Object]"]
```

This is why you're getting the last value for all 4 keys.

**Here is you're code reworked to perform as intended**

```
var object_id = 0; /* global object instance id */
function Vertex(x, y, z) {
    this.x = parseInt(x);
    this.y = parseInt(y);
    this.z = parseInt(z);
    this.id = (object_id++); /* add id to object */
};
/* override to string so it can be used as a key */
Vertex.prototype.toString = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}

var set = {};

var v1 = new Vertex(1,2,3);
var v2 = new Vertex(2,3,4);
var v3 = new Vertex(1,2,3);
var v4 = new Vertex(4,5,6);

set[v1] = 10;
set[v2] = 11;


alert(set[v1] + " " + set[v2] + " " + set[v3] + " " + set[v4]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Object properties are strings so if you try to do `set[v1] = 10;`, `v1` will be converted to a string (the string will be `[object Object]`) so essentially you'll get `set['[object Object]'] = 10;` this will occur for all your objects and each value you set will overwrite the previous.

So you code is equivalent to this

```
function Vertex(x, y, z) {
    this.x = parseInt(x);
    this.y = parseInt(y);
    this.z = parseInt(z);
};

var set = {};

var v1 = new Vertex(1,2,3);
var v2 = new Vertex(2,3,4);
var v3 = new Vertex(1,2,3);
var v4 = new Vertex(4,5,6);

set['[object Object]'] = 10;
set['[object Object]'] = 11;          

alert(set['[object Object]'] + " " + set['[object Object]'] + " " + set['[object Object]'] + " " + set['[object Object]']);
// Output: 11 11 11 11
```